# Ubuntu 13.10 not working properly after executing command

Tags: system

After running the command

`sudo rm -fR /var/lib/apt/lists/*`,

my system ain't working properly & many of the applications aren't opening.
When my pc boots, black screen appears for some time.

Can any one help?

Answer (score 0):

Type this in terminal

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get upgrade`

This will re-create that file & upgrade your packages & as stated in comments below,

`sudo do-release-upgrade` will you to Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: can i run the command sudo do-release-upgrade directly

Comment: sorry, didnt get you!

Comment: If you can't get a terminal up to run them, press ctrl+alt+1 to go into one of your tty (ctrl+alt+1 through ctrl+alt+6 bring you to one of six of these with ctr+alt+7 bringing you back to the graphical shell). Type your username, and then your password when prompted for it, and then you can run the commands there.

Comment: i want to upgrade it to 14.04 so can i run this command sudo do-release-upgrade without running the above command?

Comment: @JonHanna its Alt+Ctrl+F2 & Alt+Ctrl+F7 correct it!

Comment: yes! sudo do-release-upgrade upgrades your ubuntu to 14.04 but that isnt an answer this question

Comment: mind sudo do-release-upgrade it will delete everything except your `/home` folder

Comment: means first is should run the above two command and then sudo do-release-upgrade command

Comment: yes, first execute above commands check whether you can solve your question. & then you can do `sudo do-release-upgrade` command for upgrading

Comment: Jax-L, you are of course completely right, I suffered from one of those cases where one makes a mistake once and then keeps on doing it, which is now cringeworthy. Sadly too late to edit my comment.

Comment: i ran the above two command but while unpacking error occurred .no chroot environment found so it trying to connect with site but unable to connect .what should i do now

Comment: did you write `sudo` before `do-release-upgrade` ?